# SciTE won't remember recent files, even though preferences are set correctly

Tags: lubuntu, session, scite

I'm running Lubuntu and SciTE. I've never had this problem in the past with SciTE, but recently it's stopped remembering the session and the recent files. I have the following set in Global Options:

```
save.recent=1
save.session=1
```

And though that's always worked in the past, it doesn't work now. (When I run "sudo scite", it DOES remember the recent files that I open, but only the ones I've opened under sudo.)

Happy to answer any questions you might have, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! Solved it. I filed a bug report with the programmer, and he recommended that instead of using Global Options, I should use User Options (which doesn't require sudo).

After mucking around a bit, I found the solution:

1. Purge Scite.
2. Delete the User Options and Sessions files from my home directory.
3. Reinstall Scite.
4. Add this:

   save.recent=1

   save.session=1

To the User Options.